# Docker and conda - how does "clean --all -y" work?

Tags: python, docker, conda

I am bit confused by the conda command `conda clean --all -y` inside a docker script.
Generally, the idea is to shrink the final docker image. `conda clean --all -y` should help to delete downloaded tarballs, and indeed, the docker log shows:

```
Will remove 430 (853.4 MB) tarball(s).
```

However, the final image size is identical whether I include `conda clean --all -y` or not. Do I additionally need to explicitly delete any files with `rm -rf` or how can you explain that the final image size is not different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a `conda` issue, but a Docker issue. The layers in a Dcoker image are read-only; you can't modify them. When you create an image with something like

```
RUN conda do_something
RUN conda clean --all -y
```

whatever the first command added to the image is *fixed* in that layer. The subsequent command doesn't remove anything from the *image*, only that layer.

To avoid adding the tarballs to the image in the first place, you need to remove them *immediately* during the creation of that layer, after you are doing using them but before the layer is fixed in the image.

```
RUN conda do_something && conda clean --all -y
```

Comment: I can confirm now I see a difference of roughly 1GB - great!

Comment: I feel like there should be a canonical answer for this extremely common issue, but I don't know the [docker] tag well enough.