# Docker and tensorflow - image size explodes with tensorflow

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, pip, conda

I am trying to add tensorflow to my conda enviroment by adding the following depenencies to my .yml enviroment file

```
name: py310
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - pandas
```

#### Additional tensorflow dependencies

```
  - pip
  - cudatoolkit=11.2 
  - cudnn=8.1.0
  - pip:
    - keras-tuner
    - tensorflow>2.0
```

The image size is +3-4GB larger with tensorflow and its dependencies. Is this what I should expect or can I somehow reduce the size of this installation (for example, I don't need the GPU support).

The base image is: `FROM condaforge/mambaforge`

Comment: In my experience this can indeed happen when you combine docker with conda, although 6-7GB is a larger increase then I've ever seen. You don't specify your base image, but you could check if starting out with a [tensorflow image](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow) reduces your image size and if using only pip (without conda at all) reduces the size even further.

Comment: I am trying to switch from pip to conda as we have issues to get additional third party libraries to work with pip, currently only conda solves this problem. I added the base image above.

Comment: Ok, that's a pity. In my experience conda always adds a ton of overhead. But if it must be conda: have you looked into [micromamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/micromamba-docker)? And perhaps [multi-stage builds](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/conda-docker-image-size/) are an option for you ([here's another link](https://blog.ceshine.net/post/docker-multi-stage-build/))?

Comment: I highly recommend Uwe's blog post for tips on optimizing container size when using Conda: https://uwekorn.com/2021/03/01/deploying-conda-environments-in-docker-how-to-do-it-right.html

Comment: Is this already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75521592/570918 ? That is, the issue is being unaware that `RUN cmd_A; RUN cmd_B` generates (often heavy) intermediates with each separate `RUN` directive, whereas idiomatic usage is `RUN cmd_A && cmd_B`.

Comment: Yes, it partially solves the problem - it reduces the size difference to 3.5GB vs. 6-7GB. I still think 3.5GB is too large for single package. I tried to shrink the conda image using pythonspeed.com/docker - it helps to some extend, but not everything works for us.